# Converting C# RegEx to JavaScript gives error Invalid Group

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have the following C# Regular Expression:

```
var r = new Regex(@"
                (?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]) |
                 (?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z]) |
                 (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

r.Replace(PageName, " ")
```

And I'm trying to convert it to JavaScript:

```
 var r= new RegExp('(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]) | (?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z]) | (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])');

PageName.split(pageRegex).join(" ")
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]) | (?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z]) | (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])/: Invalid group
```

Update: Some examples of what the RegEx should convert:

- AllPeople to All People
- PeopleCRB to People CRB
- People to People

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/fX8tJ4/1). It seems that your brackets starting with (? are a problem

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what your regex does so we can help more

Comment: @RedLaser provided some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|([^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])
```

Javascript doesn't support lookbehind: `(?<=` So make the lookbehind a group and replace it later.

Replace by `$1$2$3` . See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/11

```
var re = /([A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|([^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])/gm;
var str = 'AllPeople\nPeopleCRB\nPeople';
var subst = '$1$2$3 ';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Tried your expression, but it doesn't convert `PeopleCRB` to `People CRB` it converts it to `Peopl e CRB`

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use your expression? as I have done: `PageName.split(pageRegex).join(" ")` where `pageRegex` is your expression. Is this correct for your example?

Comment: Actually it converts it to `Peopl  e  CRB` - See the double spacing!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean `Replace by $1$2$3` can you show an example of how you are doing the split and join using this.